# When to use multiple instances of Spring Container?

Tags: java, spring

I am using ApplicationContext as a Spring Container.

However, since I don't want to change my API, I feel the need to use multiple instances of the container as follows -

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 { 
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

    ...
    objA = context.getBean(...);
    objB = context.getBean(...);
 }

// code for Class A

 public void execute() // <-- cannot change this signature 
 {
     ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
     objC = context.getBean(...); // earlier, this was objC = new C();
     objC.method1("...");
 }
```

So I end up using two different instances of ApplicationContext. When is it appropriate and when is it not appropriate to have multiple instances of ApplicationContext?

Comment: For the majority of applications there should be no need for multiple ApplicationContexts. The main limitation is that you cannot share bean instances across containers. Technically there is no reason why you can't break them up into two containers, but you'll have to duplicate beans instances if you need them in both, and hence consume more memory. Why is this API you speak of requiring multiple containers?

Comment: Can you put the application context in a static variable in your main, then allow access it from everywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the classes, try to implement ApplicationContextAware:
 http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html

This will inject the applicationContext into the class giving you the liberty to get any class you need.

As long as class `A` is initialized by spring this will work.  From the code given this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

For the majority of applications there should be no need for multiple ApplicationContexts. The main limitation is that you cannot share bean instances across containers. Technically there is no reason why you can't break them up into two containers, but I'm sure there will be some common beans you will want to share like dataSources, and a common business layer, etc.

Looking at your example I'd recommend allowing your class A to accept a SpringApplication context as a constructor (alternatively you could use a setter method)

```
public class A {

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public A(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {   
        ctx = applicationContext;
    }

    public void execute() {
        // do stuff with beans retrieved from "ctx"
    }
}
```

Your main() will bootstrap; the context and pass it to an instance of `A`

```
public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A(SpringContextFactory.getInstance());

        a.execute();        
    }
}
```

As an extra piece of good design, encapsulate your creation of the context inside a Factory class

```
public class SpringContextFactory {

    public static ApplicationContext getInstance() {

        String[] contextXml = new String[]{ "resources/spring-context.xml",
                                            "resources/spring-db.xml" };

        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextXml);
    }
}
```

I have found this setup works well with my unit tests

Comment: Your post gave me an idea. I think I will create the ApplicationContext as a singleton.

Comment: Creating a singleton is imho a bad idea since if you run multiple applications in the same jvm you will run into problems.  I already encountered this issue and it s**ks to debug.

Answer (score 1):

For my tests, I crated a utilities class and simply used a static instance and created a singleton.

For example:

```
 public class Utilities {
private static ApplicationContext _applicationContext = null; 
private static void initApplicationContext() {
        if (_applicationContext == null) {
            _applicationContext = 
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("PersistenceHelper-context.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Then anytime you need it, just say:

```
Utilities.initApplicationContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you are not using Spring correctly.  The idea is to wire up your dependencies in Spring and then use one `ApplicationContext` to load your starting bean (likely from your `main()` method).  It is not ideal to load the same context multiple times in multiple places just to get different beans.

From what I can tell, your code for `ClassA` should be trying to `@Autowired` an instance of `ClassC` (or `ObjectC`) to its member.  You want to do this because `ClassA` is already a Spring defined bean!  Depending on the scope provided to Spring for your `ClassC` bean, you should either inject the bean directly (for the `singleton` scope):

```
@Autowired
private ClassC objC;
```

Or you should inject a factory for creating instances of the bean (for the `prototype` scope):

```
@Autowired
private ClassCFactory objCFactory;
```

If you make this change, then you have no need to load the `ApplicationContext` more than once.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have mulitple application context. In many cases, we need a shared application context.

In order to avoid creating multiple application context in the  application, do the following.

When the applicationcontextprovider bean is created, spring framework will inject the ApplicationContext into the setApplicationContext.

Now we have one static utility method getApplicationContext, which will return the application context whenever required.

whenever you need the application context , you just say:ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();  , which will return the shared application context.

/* Application Context Provider class */

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationContextProvider.class);

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0)
            throws BeansException {
        if (arg0 != null) {
            ctx=arg0;
        }
    }

    public synchronized static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
        if (ctx==null) {
            logger.info("Getting the context again as it is null");
            ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-All-Module.xml");
        }
        return ctx;
    }


}
```

Spring Xml:

```
<bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="dell.harmony.service.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>
```

From your main program class:

```
try {
            logger.info("Spring Application Context !!");
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "/Spring-All-Module.xml");
            logger.info("Spring Application Context - End !!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Exception in getting the Spring Application Context !!");
                     /* log the exception */
        }
```

Whenever you need the context, you simply say:
//get application context

ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
dl = (SingleDataLoader) context.getBean("singledataloaderdao");

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `context` and just a put `application context` into YOUR PROGRAM CONTEXT in main method, in other methods you have to just get, in your case use static method from some Context class, it is not a good but you cannot change API